# Is there a way to "stream" curl response to browser?

Tags: php, curl, stream

When connecting to a game server, the client is given step-by-step instructions to display to the player. By doing a cURL, it becomes clear that the instructions are given one after the other, at intervals of a few seconds. My script is meant to be between the client and the server. I can "intercept" the instructions, but when my script sends them back to the client, it gives them all at the same time.
Is there a way to do the same as for a proxy with the HTTP stream through a PHP script?

the part of my cURL code:

```php
$ch = curl_init("http://my_game_server_ip:port/connect".$getFields); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: MySafeUserAgent', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

Thanks a lot !